# How to know that two javascript variable point to the same memory address

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to know that 2 javascript variable point to the same memory address ?

```
var my_var = {
    id: 1,
    attribute: "myAttribute"
}

var copy = my_var;

//someting like
if(copy === my_var) return true;
```

Comment: Well, you've answered your own question. :) This is true only for objects though.

Comment: `===` means that 2 vars have same type, in your case `Object` and this will be `true`. This will not check for same `memory allocation`

Comment: It also means that they are the same object. I don't know of any JS engine which would have two separate memory allocations in such a situation.

Comment: @antyrat No, `===` checks type **and** value. If both sides are objects it checks whether they point to the same address. That's it.

Comment: @antyrat It's strict equality. They have to be of the same type **and** have the same value. In the case of objects, "have the same value" is synonymous with "be the same object", which implies they occupy the same memory address(es).

Comment: So if `copy === my_var` returns true it means they both point to the same memory address. Are you 100% sure?

Comment: @Lorenzo Yes, 100% sure.

Comment: This is correct, x = { one: 1 }, y = { one: 1 }; x === y is false, they are only equivalent if they point to the same space.  For comparing objects you generally will want to compare properties on the object, libs like lodash/underscore are good for this

Comment: How about 2 vars are primitive type value? for example:  var str1 = "foo"; var str2 = "foo"; if(str1 === str2) return true; Can we say these 2 variables point to the same memory address ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't alias variables like you can in C.  In javascript, something like

```
var x = 1;
var y = x
y = 4;
// x is still 1
```

will always be the case.

However, objects are always passed by reference

```
var x = { one: 1, two: 2 };
var y = x;
y.one = 100;
// x.one is now 100
```

Comment: -1: In case of objects "equality" means "the same memory reference".

Comment: You are correct, removed that from the post as I think it is exaplined better above.

Comment: Also the first piece of code would produce the same result in C as well. Actually variable assignment works **exactly** the same as in C. The difference is in: 1) passing variables to functions, 2) there is no reference/pointer operator in JavaScript (i.e. you can't work with memory directly).

Comment: (thumbsup), I guess I should have included a C example with pointer operations, they were excluded because javascript doesn't have them .. wording is a little unclear, I suppose.

Answer (score 20):

> Is there a way to know if 2 javascript variable point to the same memory address ?

Generally the answer is *no*. Primitive types (like numbers) are being passed around by value. So we have

```
> var x = 1;
> var y = 1;
> x === y;
true
```

even though they don't refer to the same memory location (well, this is an implementation detail, but they are not pointing to the same memory address at least in V8).

But when both sides are objects then *yes: use `==` or `===`*. If both sides are objects then each operator checks whether they point at the same memory address.

```
> var x = {test: 1};
> var y = {test: 1};
> x === y;
false
```

Comment: so in the first example, are x and y pointing to the same 1? please

Comment: @Matian2049 As in the same memory address? That is an implementation detail and depends on the JavaScript engine you are using. For example under V8 (Chrome's JS) the answer is no: that's because primitives live on the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. that's what i meant, if 1 and 1 share same memo addr. that's clear now.

Comment: so i'm debating w/ myself. when var a = 1; var b = a; is 1 copied to b or is be pointing to the first 1 created for a?

Comment: @Matian2049 It is copied. Try this: `var a = 1; var b = a; a = 2; console.log(b);` It will print `1`.

Comment: interestingly, if a points to 1, then b points to 1, a re-points to 2, b still points to 1. looks like i have created a mirror logic world.. haha thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript when we declare more than one variable with same value then each and every variable points same memory location.Basically javascript follow the reference counting algorithm.same things happen in Python.

Comment: Hw to proof `each and every variable point same memory location` by a program?

Answer (score -6):

In Python, you can use `id(variableName)` to get the memory address:

```
>>> x = "hello world"
>>> id(x)
4347327152
>>> x = 2
>>> id(x)
4305328544
```

But I don't know the how to achieve it in JavaScript. Otherwise, we can also easily see whether two pointers point to the same address. Hopefully my answer provides some useful information.

Comment: this is exactly what im trying to find and none of the other answers help at all! i need a javascript version of python's `id` built-in

Comment: I do not think this answer deserves such a amount of hateness. For all the people who vote down, this answer could dive to a proper search to the people who is looking for something similar in Javascript.

Comment: Exactly, in python when you do `x = 1` and then `x = y`, `x` and `y` share the same reference to the memory address. I still don't understand whether in javaScript happens the same.

Comment: For all the people who voted down, at-least add a reason to do so.

Comment: @Himanshu Clearly, this answer doesn't answer the question. "Can be done in python and not sure about Javascript" is more like an acceptable comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Himanshu It's because the question is about  JavaScript and the answer is about Python.