# does javascript have something equivalent to Python's `id` function?

Tags: javascript, python

I'm struggling with some **d3.js v4** troubleshooting and I suspect that some objects that I think are the same are not, in fact, the same object.

In Python I could do `print("obj1:%s" % (id(obj1)))`, `print("obj2:%s" % (id(obj2)))`.

That gives me the Python memory allocation for the object and if they match I know they are the  same objects.  Is there anything equivalent in JS?

This is related to [How to know that javascript variable point to the same memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457644/how-to-know-that-javascript-variable-point-to-the-same-memory-address), but unlike that case, both references are not in scope at the same time so I can't `===` them.

Comment: Interesting question, but probably duplicate. In essence, as I understand them, the answers in the linked Q+A can be summarized as "there is no native identifier, but you can implement your own".

Comment: yeah, i'm good with the duplicate.  not all that happy with the answer, but hey, that's nothing to do with SO.