# Does useRef stores address for variables in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-ref

Does useRef store address for variables?

```
const x = useRef(data);
const y = x;
```

I'll have two separate copies of data or one? What will be the memory consumption? What are the drawbacks of this method?

Comment: `useRef` doesn't copy data.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would like to use JS as some other languages (C ?) - but keep in mind that they are differences. Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21457798

Your example looks like trying of copy useRef object. Before you go to useRef, remember how to copy objects in JS example here:
[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)