# Can i get a actual memory address in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
const a = 'a'
const b = [a]
a === b[0] // true
```

is `a` and `b[0]` has different address? i learned `===` only compare value and values type copy of primitive type in javascript is deep copy

i want know `===` is compare real memory address??
and is there any way can get a memory address in javascript??

i tried to find way but i can't

please let me know your wise
have a nice day!!

Comment: Why? What purpose would it serve?

Comment: look these answers:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530936/is-there-any-method-to-check-memory-address-of-javascript-variable
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457644/how-to-know-that-two-javascript-variable-point-to-the-same-memory-address